# Jasmine UI automation

Tags: jasmine, jasmine-jquery, jasmine2.0

I have set up my jasmine framework using the steps mentioned [here](https://jasmine.github.io/setup/nodejs.html), but when I try to use jasmine keywords like `browser.open` to open a URL in the Browser I get an error `browser not defined`. When I use `require` to get another page, it gives `Reference error: module not found`.

Also, with my jasmine package, I did not get the `specRunner.html`.

I have tried installing protractor also and different approaches, but it's not working.

I need to set up jasmine framework for UI automation, can anyone help me with the exact set up and issues that I am facing right now?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you please include a code snippet of what you have tried so far?

Comment: browser().navigate('https://www.google.com');

Answer (score 0):

The jasmine library is not related to browser automation. It is a library about testing. It does not define the `browser` object. I'm not sure which library you expect to require. Perhaps you want to use [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/). In particular, you will want to look at the [WebDriver API](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/).

It allows you to do things [like this](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp):

```
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().build();
driver.get('http://www.google.com');

var element = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q'));
element.sendKeys('Cheese!');
element.submit();

driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
  console.log('Page title is: ' + title);
});

driver.wait(function() {
  return driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
    return title.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf('cheese!', 0) === 0;
  });
}, 3000);

driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
  console.log('Page title is: ' + title);
});

driver.quit();
```